# Why are event IDs 4802 and 4803 missing? Worked in the past

Tags: windows-7

[image]

Even if it is enabled, event ID 4802 and 4803 are missing from Security Logs.

Prior to 1/3/22 11:17:40.000 AM was working fine, after that, events are missing.

I tried to unconfigure and configure it from `gpedit.msc`, done couple restarts, I even looked in regedit to see if I see something that makes sense, but to no avail.

Where do I need to look in order to repair this, and what can I do more than I already did?

Comment: This is related to your screensaver.  Does this article help you?   https://www.manageengine.com/products/active-directory-audit/kb/logon-logoff-events/event-id-4802.html#:~:text=The%20screensaver%20was%20invoked.,workstation%2C%20event%204803%20is%20generated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I know all that is to be known about Windows logs and EventIds. The problem is that in my security log is not getting in EventId 4802 and 4803. I susspect that this happened in december 30 2021 when i played a bit with logging system and put way too many, or problematic, loggers to gather data. I need to investigate this a bit, as in to disable what i have enabled back then. But what i already have disabled, didn't solved the main problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you need to set a screensaver, be it atleast blank.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsOLL.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdFG8.png)

Answer (score 0):

That does not seem to be the complete solution for Windows 11, I not only enabled other logon/logoff audit events, but setup a screen saver as well.  And still do not see 4802 or 4803 events, anyone else have this issue as well on Windows 11?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1127668)

Comment: Right, but since I cannot add comments... I added what I could where I could... BECAUSE THE FEATURE APPEARS TO BE BROKEN IN Windows 11.  So people need to know this.  Interesting that this system censors new users, no wonder it rarely has helpful information?

Comment: you should have asked on my answer, not post another response.